# Random Walk on $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, random-walk

Let $\phi_j$ be independent and uniformaly distrubited random variables on $[0, 2\pi)$.
Then we define the random Walk on $\mathbb{C}$ as follows: $$\sum_{j=1}^nae^{i\phi_j}$$
where $a \in \mathbb{R}$. Is possible to calculate the probability that $|\sum_{j=1}^nae^{i\phi_j}| \le c$ accurately?

Comment: How accurately, and for what kind of $c$ values?  I am pretty sure there is a closed-form solution to this problem (classically known as the "problem of random flights")  involving Bessel functions.  The classical limit theorems of probability theory (such as the central limit theorem) will give approximations valid for large $n$.

Comment: $c \le n, c \in \mathbb{R}$. It is kinda late over here so I will read up on the "problem of random flights" later today.

Comment: @kimchilover do you know an open source where I can read on the problem of random flights?

Comment: and how close is: $\mathbb{P}(|\sum_{j=1}^nae^{i\phi_j}| \le c) = \frac{c}{n}$

Comment: Let $(A_n,B_n)=\sum_{j=1}^n(\cos(\phi_j),\sin(\phi_j))$.  Then $(A_n,B_n)/\sqrt n$ converges in distribution to a standard bivariate normal distribution, and $S_n=|(A_n,B_n)|^2/n$ converges in distribution to a $\chi^2$ distribution: $P(S_n\le x)\to 1-\exp(-x/2)$. This might contain enough information for you to use.  I am away from my library and don't have a good reference on random flights for you.